# Discord bot in JavaScript and Minecraft server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, minecraft

I'm just trying to program a simple Discord bot, which will check some discord user his role and if he has a white-listed role, he will be added to the white-list on my Minecraft server.

You know sub server, but I need this bot, after he get that user own this role. I need him to write the name to the Minecraft whitelist on VPS, where the bot will be hosted too, and I'm looking for syntax. I found `fs.appendfile`, but that's only for text in the bot folder. I need him to get in Minecraft folder, and add it to `whitelist.txt` is it possible? And is it possible remove names from white-list too?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily edit files in another folder. But to modify this way, you may need to reload the server. You're better off using a package to send a `/whitelist` command (like [`minecraft-protocol`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minecraft-protocol))

Editing files in another folder:

```js
fs.appendFileSync('../thisFileIsOneFolderAboveTheCurrentWorkingDir', 'foo');
```